# how to navigate the particular page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have admin panel side bar like as follow

```
 <li class="<?= (uri_string() == 
"admin/customer_personal/listcustomerpersonal")?"active":NULL;?>">
 <a href="<?php echo 
 base_url('admin/customer_personal/listcustomerpersonal'); ?>">
 <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> View Customer Personal
  </a>
 </li>
```

my view file is locate in admin/customer_personal/listcutomer.php then my controller file is

```
<?php
   if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Cus_personal extends MX_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')==FALSE)
    {
        redirect('auth','refresh');
    }
    //$this->load->model('model_customer_personal');
    $this->load->library('api_lib');
}
function index()
{
    $this->listcustomerpersonal();
}
function listcustomerpersonal()
{
    //$data['customers']=$this->load->get_customerall();
    //$this->theme_lib->data = $data;
    $this->theme_lib->view ='customer_personal/listcustomerpersonal';
    $this->theme_lib->title = 'D2D | Customer Attendance';
   // $this->theme_lib->pageFoot 
  ='customer_personal/listcustomerpersonalfoot';
    //$this->theme_lib->pageHead 
 ='customer_personal/listcustomerpersonalhead';
    $this->theme_lib->render();
    }
    }
   ?>
```

then my view file is

```
<?php
echo '<h1>hai hello how are you</h1>';
?>
```

but i have an error as 404 page not found error but other page in this panels were worked.

Comment: your controller name is cus_personal, not customer_personal so URL is <a href="<?php echo 
 base_url('admin/cus_personal/listcustomerpersonal'); ?>">

Answer (score 0):

I guess your controller file is also located on path **admin/customer_personal/**. If yes, then you need to change your change below line

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/customer_personal/listcustomerpersonal'); ?>">
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/customer_personal/Cus_personal/'); ?>">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the route for the url in config > routes as below

```
  $route['admin/customer_personal/listcustomerpersonal'] = 'admin/cus_personal/listcustomerpersonal';
```

or change the url in the side bar like

```
<li class="<?= (uri_string() == 
"admin/customer_personal/listcustomerpersonal")?"active":NULL;?>">
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/cus_personal/listcustomerpersonal'); ?>">
 <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> View Customer Personal
  </a>
 </li>
```